# Recent Source for rtl8192su

Tags: wifi, usb, raspbian-buster

---

I'm having trouble with a WiFi dongle that shows up on lsusb as 0bda:8172
It was working on my Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2 running Buster until a kernel update.
The current kernel is 5.10.63+
Nothing is available through install-wifi from MrEngman

I found good instructions here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2185 with instructions for compiling the r92su driver (replacing the r8712u driver).

Unfortunately the module does not compile because of changes:

e.g. eth_change_mtu has been deprecated.

Can anyone point me to a more recent copy of the rtl8192u (and/or r92su) source code so that I can compile it against the current kernel and get my wifi adapter working again.

I ultimately want to use this dongle with my Raspberry Pi Model B Rev 2 running Bullseye and the same kernel version.

I've spent about two frustrating weeks following several leads that all ended up in a morass of confusion.

Comment: The answer you don't like, dont buy network devices with Realtek chips. Realtek has a lousy relationship with Linux, they dont care.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the OP's question:

> Can anyone point me to a more recent copy of the rtl8192u (and/or
> r92su) source code so that I can compile it against the current kernel
> and get my wifi adapter working again.

and here is my answer:

I've built both r92su and rtl8192su drivers for recent kernels from the source code here: https://github.com/jschultz/rtl8192su.git

However I find that the although the rtl8192su driver supports Master mode it doesn't work properly with hostapd.